# Javascript variable cut off after apostrophe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a Javascript which reads the text from two HTML drop-down lists, removes all special characters, and then stores the text in a variable. The text in the drop-down lists are coming from a JSON file. The problem is that whenever the text from the drop-down lists has an apostrophe, the Javascript cuts the string at the apostrophe, hence all text after the apostrophe is not included in the Javascript variable.

I have included a replace rule to try and replace all apostrophes with a non-space, but no luck. I cannot avoid the problem by using HEX codes, since the Javascript reads text directly from the HTML drop-down lists.

Example: If a user selects "Belgium" and "Braine-l'Allerud" in the drop-down lists, the javascript should create a variable "Cities-belgium-brainelallerud.html". Instead, it cuts all text after the apostrophe in "Braine-l'Allerud" and instead creates a variable "Cities-belgium-brainel.html"

Here is the JSON file (basis for the text in drop-down lists):

```
"austria": "Hirschegg,Salzburg,Bergheim,Wien",
"belgium": "Antwerpen,Braine-l'Alleud,Brugge"
```

And here is the Javascript code:

```
jQuery( "button[type='submit']" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var var1 = $('#json-one').val()
    var var2 = $('#json-two').val().toLowerCase().replace(/'/g,"").replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/g,'')

    var link = "Cities-"+var1+"-"+var2+".html"
    console.log(link)
    document.location = link;
    });
```

The JSON values are extracted into the drop down lists by the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#json-one").change(function() {
        var $dropdown = $(this);
           $.getJSON("../jsondata/data003.json", function(data) {

                var key = $dropdown.val();
                var vals = [];

                switch(key) {
                    case 'austria':
                        vals = data.austria.split(",");
                        break;
                    case 'belgium':
                        vals = data.belgium.split(",");
                        break;
            }
                var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
                $jsontwo.empty();
                $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
                   $jsontwo.append("<option value='"+value+"'>" + value + "</option>");
                });

            });
        });
        $("#json-one").trigger('change');
    });
```

The drop-down list is dynamic; the 2nd drop down list (cities) is dependent on what the user chooses in the 1st drop down list (countries).

Finally, the drop down list is written as follows in the HTML:

```
<span class="fontyellow">Country:</span>
    <select id="json-one">
                <option value="austria">Austria</option>
                <option value="belgium">Belgium</option>
    </select>

<span class="fontyellow">City:</span>
    <select id="json-two">
    </select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show how you are extracting the JSON into the pull down list?

Comment: You've omitted the relevant code; your problem is somewhere in the conversion of your json into the `<select>` options.  (Incidentally, why are you using comma-separated strings for your city lists instead of real arrays?)

Comment: @fmacdee I have edited the description to show how I extract the JSON into the pull down list.

Comment: @Daniel Beck The strings with apostophe, such as Braine-l'Alleud is showing up correctly in the <select> drop down lists. It is only when the URL is generated by the Javascript, that the strings is cut at the apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem is in your dynamic construction of the options. You have organized your apostrophes in this manner:

```
 $jsontwo.append("<option value='"+value+"'>" + value + "</option>");
```

As a result, the single quote is surrounding the city name in the 'value' portion of this string and hence the string is cutoff at the first single apostrophe it runs into. Basically it looks like this when constructed:

```
<option value='Braine-l'Alleud'>Braine-l'Alleud</option>
```

You need to use double quotes for that portion of the string instead:

```
 $jsontwo.append('<option value="'+value+'">' + value + "</option>");
```

That will fix the problem and give you the following:

```
 <option value="Braine-l'Alleud">Braine-l'Alleud</option>
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked like a charm:-) Thank you so much for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are generating the link the way you are but if you replace the code from jQuery to javascript, it should be able to read the text.

Like below:

```
var var1 = document.getElementById("json-one").innerText;
var var2 = document.getElementById("json-two").innerText;
```

I put the html in div like below:

```
<div id="json-one">Hirschegg,Salzburg,Bergheim,Wien</div>
<div id="json-two">Antwerpen,Braine-l'Alleud,Brugge</div>
```

OR

replace .val() to .html() like below:

```
var var1 = $('#json-one').html();
var var2 = $('#json-two').html();
```

See if it helps!

Comment: I tried using the .html() option as you suggested, but this does not work as it then includes ALL countries in the JSON file when the link is generated. Also, the two drop down lists are dynamic (the country chosen in json-one will affect which cities are available in json-two, this is the reason I have the input data in an external JSON file.

Comment: Your original problem was that you were not able to read value due to character(') in Braine-l'Alleud. This solution solves that original problem. You seem to have edited the problem now. I would suggest you close this problem and create a new question for your subsequent problem so that it would attract more attention and more people will be able to help you.

Comment: The problem is still that I cannot read value due to character (') in Braine-l'Alleud, when the Javascript reads the strings from the drop down lists, and the drop down lists get their values from the JSON file. I tried your suggestions, but unfortunately they do not work the way I need to have the script work (which is link created from strings in drop down list, where external JSON is the basis of drop down values. Much appreciate your suggestions, though.